# Exported function doesn't work in if statement in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a function (getLocalSecurity) which gets an argument from command prompt and return boolean, as you see here:

```
server.ts:

    import { getDataService } from './service';
    import { getInternalService } from './internal/service';
    import { ServiceFactory } from './services/serviceFactory';

    import { loggers } from 'winston';

    const LOG = loggers.get('server');

    const mainApp = getDataService();

    const cla = require('command-line-arguments');

    const params = cla.getCommandLineArguments();

    export function getLocalSecurity(): boolean {
        return params.LOCAL_SECURITY;
    }

    LOG.info('Starting server on port 9090...');
```

On the other typeScript file I want to use it:

```
import {getLocalSecurity} from './server';

if (getLocalSecurity()) {
    console.log('access denied', getLocalSecurity());
    return Promise.resolve({});
}
```

when I use the following sentence in command prompt, getLocalSecurity is false in **console.log** but in **if** condition it is true.
What is the problem? How can I fix it?

```
npm run start  --- LOCAL_SECURITY -false
```

Comment: Have tried moving `cla.getCommandLineArguments()` inside the exported function just before return;

Comment: I tried it. no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

return is not a boolean, it is a string, I don't know why !!!!!!!
In if condition we have to use the following:

```
if (getLocalSecurity() === 'false')....
```